# Browser compatibility problem

Tags: css

This page : http://www.csgmember.com/credit-success/ works fine on FF and Chrome. It shows all the images but it's not showing images in IE. Why is that? I am using simple tables. Can anyone guess what's wrong?

Comment: Whenever anyone talks about "browser compatabality" problems, they really mean "it doesn't work in IE".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule: `#content img, #content p img {
  max-width: 100%;
}` is causing IE to freak out..  Try removing the max-width.

IE7 is supposed to support it, but its quirky.

Comment: yayy thanks alot ;) i need another help. check http://www.creditsolutiongroup.com/shanecall/ .. all the text below the blue form is in a table whose width is 640px but its spreading all over the page y?

Comment: Take a look at the the `.Blogabout p` rule. You are declaring a 943px width on the <p> tags (which I don't think you ought to be doing.)

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that the header where it says "Credit Solution Group Member" is a png. IE6 doesn't support png transparency so it creates this gray background. I would change it to a gif, it looks like a pretty simple image so wouldn't affect the quality. If you really want to keep it as a png though you can use the alpha image loader:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294714

IE 7 and 8 seems to be having a problem displaying the main images.

Edit: Yea try simshaun's suggestion